# Javascript clearInterval does not stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code that shows some messages every 6 seconds using setInterval function as bellow:

```
$(function () {
    count = 0;
    wordsArray = ["<h1>Offer received</h1>", "<h1>Offer reviewed</h1>", "<h1>Decision pending</h1>", "Offer accepted.</h1>"];

    setInterval(function () {
        $(".lead").fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).html(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
        });
        if(count === 3){
            clearInterval(window.location.href = "www.mydomain.com");
        }
        count++;
    }, 6000);
});
```

When the last message is displayed I want to redirect to a URL so I checked the counter and placed a clearInterval when the last message is displayed however it does not go to the url right after the last massage is displayed but geos back to the first one and then redirect, sounds like it continues to loop. How can I fix that please?

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass the interval that was created as the clearInterval method's parameter

Comment: It is not working when I put window.href.location after clearInterval(intervalTimer);

Comment: @oussamakamal : It should work, prepend protocol http or https may be that is the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interval id is returned by `setInterval` , you need to use that to stop particular interval.

```js
$(function() {
  count = 0;
  wordsArray = ["<h1>Offer received</h1>", "<h1>Offer reviewed</h1>", "<h1>Decision pending</h1>", "<h1>Offer accepted.</h1>"];

  var intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
    $(".lead").fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(this).html(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
    if (count === 3) {
      clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    }
    count++;
  }, 6000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lead"></div>
```

Comment: I would just add, for the OP to know, even if it may look obvious : «Then add `window.location.href = "www.mydomain.com";` on the next line. ;) +1